# Send any file with csv extension

Tags: vba, outlook

Is there is a way to send any file within a folder that has the csv extension as I will not know the name of the file ahead of time?

I believe that I have code that will allow my VBA script in combination with task scheduler to automatically send emails. I am stuck on how to attach a file that I do not know the name of.

```vb
Const cSmtpUser = "username"                                ' *** MAKE CHANGES HERE ***
Const cSmtpPassword = "password"                            ' *** MAKE CHANGES HERE ***
Const cSmtpServer = "smtp.xxx.yyy"                          ' *** MAKE CHANGES HERE ***
Const cSmtpPort = 465                                       ' *** MAKE CHANGES HERE *** (25, 465, 587 common)
Const cFromEmail = "xxxxxxxxx@xxx.yyy"                      ' *** MAKE CHANGES HERE ***
Const cToEmail = "xxxxxxxxx@xxx.yyy"                        ' *** MAKE CHANGES HERE ***
Const cSubject = "Daily Email Subject"                      ' *** MAKE CHANGES HERE ***
Const cEmailBody = "See attached for todays file."          ' *** MAKE CHANGES HERE ***
Const cAttachment = "c:\temp\yourfile.txt"                  ' *** MAKE CHANGES HERE ***

' CDO Constants needed to send email
Const cCdoSendUsingPickup = 1   'Send message using the local SMTP service pickup directory.
Const cCdoSendUsingPort = 2     'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).
Const cCdoAnonymous = 0         'Do not authenticate
Const cCdoBasic = 1             'basic (clear-text) authentication
Const cCdoNTLM = 2              'NTLM
Const cCdoSendUsingMethod        = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing"
Const cCdoSMTPServer             = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver"
Const cCdoSMTPServerPort         = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport"
Const cCdoSMTPConnectionTimeout  = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout"
Const cCdoSMTPAuthenticate       = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate"
Const cCdoSendUserName           = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername"
Const cCdoSendPassword           = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword"
Const cCdoSmtpUseSsl             = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl"

' Create filesystem object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Get a handle to the config object and it's fields
Set objConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

' Set config fields we care about
With objConfig.Fields
    .Item(cCdoSendUsingMethod)       = cCdoSendUsingPort
    .Item(cCdoSMTPServer)            = cSmtpServer
    .Item(cCdoSMTPServerPort)        = cSmtpPort
    .Item(cCdoSMTPConnectionTimeout) = 60
    .Item(cCdoSMTPAuthenticate)      = cCdoBasic
    .Item(cCdoSendUserName)          = cSmtpUser
    .Item(cCdoSendPassword)          = cSmtpPassword
    .Item(cCdoSmtpUseSsl)            = True
    .Update
End With

' Create a new message
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objMessage.Configuration = objConfig

' Populate message fields and send it
With objMessage
    .To       = cToEmail
    .From     = cFromEmail
    .Subject  = cSubject
    .Textbody = cEmailBody
    If objFSO.FileExists(cAttachment) Then
        .AddAttachment cAttachment
    End If
    .Send
End With
```

Comment: Welcome, have you looked at using the `Dir()` function with a wildcard? e.g. `*.csv` (assuming that your files will all be in the same folder each time)

Comment: I have not, I am very new to VBA and I'm not exactly sure how I would use that.

Comment: I think I figured it out, thank you for the help!

Comment: ```Dim cAttachment As String

cAttachment = Dir("C:\Users\___\Desktop\Test Folder*csv*")``` This isn't working.. thoughts? Dim cAttachment and cAttachment = are on different lines.

Comment: It should be cAttachment = Dir("C:\Users\___\Desktop\Test Folder\\*.csv").  Typing that has taught be that `\*` gets changed to `*` so your statement might not have been as wrong as it looks.  However, the trailing * is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to discover **all files** with `.csv` extension exists in a specific folder:

```
Dim oFile       As Object
Dim oFSO        As Object
Dim oFolder     As Object
Dim oFiles      As Object  

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\my\Folder\") 'Set this accordingly
Set oFiles = oFolder.Files

'For all files in the folder
For Each oFile In oFiles
    If (oFile Like "*.csv") Then
        'Add this file to attachments
        objMessage.AddAttachment oFile.Path
    End If
Next
```

Hope this helps.